# Access variable from function to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have two function that separate from each other but I want to make these functions share variable.

in this example I have very basic function that print out variable I call it `nameOutside`

```
function nameOutside() {
    console.log(name);
}
```

in this example I have `nameInside` function and it has variable called `name` and I have in the bottom of the function another function `nameOutside` and I want this function to print out name without passing into the function ( because it inside the `nameInside` function)

```
function nameInside() {
    let name = "my name";
    nameOutside();
}
```

The problem is that `nameOutside` function doesn't have an access to `name` variable
How can I make it accessible to `nameInside` function without passing into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object oriented programming, different methods (functions) of an object can share common variables using the 'this' keyword. Here in this example I declare a class called 'Context' with two methods 'nameOutside' and 'nameInside'. Then I instantiate an object from the class, storing the reference in the 'context' variable. Finally I call the nameInside() method of that object.

```js
class Context {
  nameOutside() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  nameInside() {
    this.name = "my name";
    this.nameOutside();
  }
}

let context = new Context();
context.nameInside();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to `name` variable, you have to define `nameOutside()` inside `nameInside()`:

```js
function nameInside() {
    let name = "my name";

    function nameOutside() {
        console.log(name);
    }

    nameOutside();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would not be a good practice to do so. Pass name as variable another method and use so.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the `name` variable global

```
let name;
function nameInside() {
  name = "my name"; // global variable
  nameOutside();
}

function nameOutside() {
  console.log(name);
}

nameInside();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for you reference on global variables(an undeclared variable is global in JS)

To get the variable in `window object`

```
window.name = "my name";

function nameInside() {
  nameOutside();
}

function nameOutside() {
  console.log(window.name);
  console.log(name); // both with give same output
}

nameInside();
```

Comment: Sorry but what kind of variable is that I know you can create using `var`, `const` or `let`

Comment: A variable without var, const or let is global, or wait I will add the variable declaration on the code itself

Comment: So that variable will be available on window object or it will only be available on function scope

Comment: window object, you can acsess it from anywhere inside your code file. Although it is not a best practice to define global variables and should be done only when essential

Comment: First before you add variable declaration `let name;` it was work just fine but will it be accessible in window object ?